# In OpenGL, How can I determine the bounds of the view at a given depth

Tags: math, opengl

I'm playing around with OpenGL and I've got a question that I haven't been able to find an answer to or at least haven't found the right way to ask search engines. I have a a pretty simple setup. An 800x600 viewport and a projection matrix with a 45 degree field of view and near and far planes of 1.0 and 200.0. For the sake of discussion, the modelview matrix is the identity matrix.

What I'm trying to determine is the bounds of the view at a given depth. For example, (0,0,0) is the center of the screen. And I'm looking in the -Z direction.

I want to know, if I draw geometry on a plane 100 units into the screen (0,0,-100), what are the bounds of the view? How far in the x and y direction can I draw in this plane and the geometry still be visible.

More generically, Given a plane parallel to the near and far plane (and between them), what are the visible bounds of that plane?

Also, if what I'm trying to determine has a common name or is a common operation, what's it called? That way I can track down more reading material

Comment: Reverse projection? View clipping?

Comment: The view frustum is a capped pyramid, thus the [intercept theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) applies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your view angle is 45 degrees, you have a plane at a distance of a away from the camera, with an unkown height h. The whole thing looks like this:
[image: Diagram]
Note that the angle here is half of your field of view.

Dusting off the highschool maths books, we get:

```
tan(angle) = h/a
```

Rearrange for h and subsitute the half field of view:

```
h = tan(FieldOfView / 2) * a;
```

This is how much your plane extends upwards along the Y axis.

Since screens aren't square, the width of your plane is different to the height. More exactly, the width is the aspect ratio times the height. I.e. `w = h * aspectRatio`

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank You! It's time for me to revisit my math books.